# Error CalledFromWrongThreadException when debugging rxjava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have next code.

```
private val observeRefresh = detailView.observeRefresh
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map { _ -> detailModel.forecastCity }
            .flatMap { city ->
                detailModel.getForecast(city.id, FORECAST_COUNT)
                        .map { response -> DetailUiModel.stateSuccess(response.list, detailModel.forecastCity) }
                        .onErrorReturn { t -> DetailUiModel.stateError(t.message) }
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .startWith(DetailUiModel.stateLoading)
            }
            .subscribe { this.handleResponse(it) }


private fun handleResponse(model: DetailUiModel) {
        detailView.setLoading(model.isLoading)
        when {
            model.success -> detailView.setForecastItems(model.data!!)
            !model.isLoading -> detailView.showError(model.error)
            model.city != null -> detailView.setMapImage(createMapUrl(model.city!!))
            else -> return
        }

    }
```

I want to debug this line `detailView.setMapImage(createMapUrl(model.city!!))` When I add checkpoint application throws error `CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`
If I don't add checkpoint application working fine.

Comment: try adding subscribeOn(...) and moving .observeOn() up so .map will follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flatMap` may not emit from the same thread as it receives items from, so you have to make sure the events are received on the desired thread by observing on there after the `flatMap` operator:

```
detailView.observeRefresh
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map { _ -> detailModel.forecastCity }
        .flatMap { city ->
            detailModel.getForecast(city.id, FORECAST_COUNT)
                    .map { response -> 
                        DetailUiModel.stateSuccess(response.list,
                            detailModel.forecastCity) 
                    }
                    .onErrorReturn { t -> DetailUiModel.stateError(t.message) }
        }
        .startWith(DetailUiModel.stateLoading)       // <---------------------------
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())   // <---------------------------
        .subscribe { this.handleResponse(it) }
```

There is no need for that inner `observeOn` anymore, plus, it is advised you move out `startWith` as well and before `observeOn` to make sure that initial state signal also arrives on the correct thread before the `observeRefresh` starts.

Comment: thanks. Now everything working. Interesting, why Jake Warthon showed that method if it is not working

Comment: As you have experienced, it might work sometimes when timing is just right. The rule of thumb should be to put `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` as close as possible to the `subscribe` call or to a processing step which should happen on the main thread and you may have to repeatedly apply it when there are more than one such location.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` right before `.subscribe { this.handleResponse(it)`
here is full code:

```
private val observeRefresh = detailView.observeRefresh
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map { _ -> detailModel.forecastCity }
        .flatMap { city ->
            detailModel.getForecast(city.id, FORECAST_COUNT)
                    .map { response -> DetailUiModel.stateSuccess(response.list, detailModel.forecastCity) }
                    .onErrorReturn { t -> DetailUiModel.stateError(t.message) }
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .startWith(DetailUiModel.stateLoading)
        }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { this.handleResponse(it) }
```

Comment: but I'm adding this method after `.onErrorReturn { t -> DetailUiModel.stateError(t.message) }` ?? This wouldn't be enough?

Comment: interesting thing that it is working when debug checkpoint not added

Comment: No. that observeOn is for another observable that return from getForecast function. But this observeOn is for your main Observable that you write subscribe.